# getting a value in binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

i'm trying to get a set of values in a binary image for inverting it.. but i'm having troubles to index the matrix, the first lines of my code are.

```
std::string path = "img/lena.jpg";

//Our color image
cv::Mat imageMat = cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if(imageMat.empty())
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not read image " << argv[1] << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

//Grayscale matrix
cv::Mat grayscaleMat (imageMat.size(), CV_8U);

//Convert BGR to Gray
cv::cvtColor( imageMat, grayscaleMat, CV_BGR2GRAY );

//Binary image
cv::Mat binaryMat(grayscaleMat.size(), grayscaleMat.type());

//Apply thresholding
cv::threshold(grayscaleMat, binaryMat, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

Now i need to work with the values in binaryMat, but i don't know how get it...

Answer (score 3):

1: with opencv's c++ api, you don't need to allocate output/result Mat's. just leave them empty.

```
//Convert BGR to Gray
cv::Mat grayscaleMat;   
cv::cvtColor( imageMat, grayscaleMat, CV_BGR2GRAY );

//Apply thresholding
cv::Mat binaryMat;    
cv::threshold(grayscaleMat, binaryMat, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

2: now access the pixels:

```
uchar p = binaryMat.at<uchar>(y,x); // row,col world !
binaryMat.at<uchar>(5,5) = 17;
```